# URL capture in browser using UI Automation Framework makes browser cpu to go high

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

We are using UIAutomation to monitor the urls for browser, but what we observerd is when ever we start capturing the url the browser are using high cpu and its getting not responding. how come my application effects to browser to use high cpu. This issue is observed in all latest browser only earlier we never faced this kind of issue.

Here is code which i am using to get the url

```
///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Get URL by using AutomatioElement.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="process"></param>
/// <param name="logPrefix"></param>
/// <returns>Url</returns>
private string GetProcessURL(Process process, string logPrefix)
{
    AutomationElement UrlBarElement = null;
    AutomationElement mainWindowElement = null;
    AutomationElement rootElement = null;
    try
    {
        mainWindowElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        if (mainWindowElement == null)
        {
            log.Warn(logPrefix + " - Unable to capture the URL as MainWindowElement is Null.");
            return null;
        }

        switch (process.ProcessName)
        {
            case ApplicationConstants.MicrosoftEdge:
                rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(GetDesktopWindow());
                foreach (AutomationElement child in rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, PropertyCondition.TrueCondition))
                {
                    AutomationElement window = GetEdgeCommandsWindow(child);
                    if (window == null) // not edge
                        continue;
                    return GetEdgeUrl(window);
                }
                break;
            case ApplicationConstants.Opera:
                UrlBarElement = mainWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ApplicationConstants.OperaNameProperty));
                break;
            case ApplicationConstants.Chrome:
                Condition chromeConditions = new OrCondition(
                   new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit),
                   new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ApplicationConstants.ChromeNameProperty));
                UrlBarElement = mainWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ApplicationConstants.ChromeNameProperty));
                break;
            case ApplicationConstants.FireFox:
                Condition fireFoxConditions = new AndCondition(
                       new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ApplicationConstants.FireFoxNameProperty),
                       new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
                UrlBarElement = mainWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, fireFoxConditions);
                if (UrlBarElement == null)
                {
                    fireFoxConditions = new OrCondition(
                   new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit),
                   new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text));
                    UrlBarElement = mainWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, fireFoxConditions);
                }
                break;
            default:
                UrlBarElement = mainWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
                break;
        }

        //Comment Before Deployment.
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);

        if (UrlBarElement != null)
        {
            return ((ValuePattern)UrlBarElement.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
        }
        else
        {
            log.Info(logPrefix + " - Unable to capture the URL because unable to detect the URLBarelement");
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exx)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        mainWindowElement = null;
        process = null;
        UrlBarElement = null;
        rootElement = null;
        //GC.Collect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does the GetProcessURL return? If not, where is it waiting?

Comment: Yes it will return the url if captured or else it will return null

Comment: Would this happen if you try to access other user interface element?

Comment: Same browser is taking high cpu.

Comment: Is this function being called in a loop? If so, this constantly incurs penalty of a cross process query. It would be better to get the appropriate element based on the browser and then subscribe to its value changed event which will not occupy CPU unless the value of the url changes.